# AngularJS/JS-how to convert hard coded value in factory by server returned value

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to implement solution given on "http://plnkr.co/edit/zsh2Bt7jBl1Z2mKKqlwa?p=preview", it is working as expected (with hard coded User details) but now when I am trying to replace the hard coded value by server response, I am not able to that - Please help

```
 var wmapp = angular
    .module('distance', [ 'wmapp.factory_restaurants', 'greatCircles' ])

    // RESTAURANTLIST CONTROLLER
    .controller(
            'restaurantlistController',
            function($scope, $rootScope, restaurantsFactory, position,
                    GreatCircle) {
                "use strict";
                $scope.restaurantList = restaurantsFactory.getRestaurants(); 
    // call
                // to
                // restaurantfactory
                $scope.position = position;

                $scope.distanceTo = function(restaurant) {
                    var distance = GreatCircle.distance(restaurant.long,
                            restaurant.lat, position.longitude,
                            position.latitude)
                    restaurant.distance = distance;
                    distance = distance.toFixed(1);
                    return distance;
                };
                $scope.totalDisplayed = 2; // implementing a load more
                // capability
                $scope.loadMore = function() {
                    $scope.totalDisplayed += 20;
                };
            })

    .factory(
            'position',
            function($rootScope) {

                console.log('building position')

                var position = {};

                // 1ST / AUTO GEOLOCATION OF USER
                // displays a popup to indicate current user location -
                // (disabled)
                // onSuccess Callback - This method accepts a Position
                // object, which contains the current GPS coordinates
                var onSuccess = function(position2) {

                    console.log(position2.coords.latitude)
                    console.log(position2.coords.longitude)

                    //alert("latitude and longitude------"
                        //  + position2.coords.latitude + "----------"
                            //+ position2.coords.longitude);

                      position.latitude = "26.805273";
                        position.longitude = "83.355463";

                    //position.latitude = position2.coords.latitude;
                    //position.longitude = position2.coords.longitude;

                    $rootScope.$digest()
                };

                function onError(error) { // onError Callback receives a
                    // PositionError object
                    alert('code: ' + error.code + '\n' + 'message: '
                            + error.message + '\n');
                }

                navigator.geolocation
                        .getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);

                return position;

            })

  angular
    .module('wmapp.factory_restaurants', [ 'greatCircles' ])

    .factory(
            'restaurantsFactory',
            function() {
                "use strict";
                var factory = {
                    Restaurants : [
                            {
                                Name : '11111111111',
                                venueType : 'Electrician ',
                                subCuisine : 'Fan',
                                subsubCuisine : 'Greesing, Bnding',
                                address : 'abc',
                                city : 'test',
                                country : 'xxx',
                                countryCode : 'kk',
                                lat : 36.805273,
                                long : 73.355463,
                            },
                            {
                                Name : '222222222',
                                venueType : 'Electrician ',
                                subCuisine : 'Fan',
                                subsubCuisine : 'Greesing, Bnding',
                                address : 'hii',
                                city : 'xyz',
                                country : 'abc',
                                countryCode : 'oo',
                                lat : 85.320918,
                                long : 43.006271,
                            } ],
                    getRestaurants : function() {
                        return factory.Restaurants;
                    },
                };
                return factory;

            });

  // 2ND / CALCULATE DISTANCE BETWEEN TWO GEOCOORDIANTES
  var GreatCircle = {

   validateRadius : function(unit) {
    var r = {
        'KM' : 6371.009,
        'MI' : 3958.761,
        'NM' : 3440.070,
        'YD' : 6967420,
        'FT' : 20902260
    };
    if (unit in r)
        return r[unit];
    else
        return unit;
    },

    distance : function(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, unit) {
    console.log(arguments)
    if (unit === undefined)
        unit = 'KM';
    var r = this.validateRadius(unit);
    lat1 *= Math.PI / 180;
    lon1 *= Math.PI / 180;
    lat2 *= Math.PI / 180;
    lon2 *= Math.PI / 180;
    var lonDelta = lon2 - lon1;
    var a = Math.pow(Math.cos(lat2) * Math.sin(lonDelta), 2)
            + Math.pow(Math.cos(lat1) * Math.sin(lat2) - Math.sin(lat1)
                    * Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(lonDelta), 2);
    var b = Math.sin(lat1) * Math.sin(lat2) + Math.cos(lat1)
            * Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(lonDelta);
    var angle = Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), b);

    return angle * r;
    },

bearing : function(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
    lat1 *= Math.PI / 180;
    lon1 *= Math.PI / 180;
    lat2 *= Math.PI / 180;
    lon2 *= Math.PI / 180;

    console.log(lat1);
    console.log(lon1);
    console.log(lat2);
    console.log(lon2);

    var lonDelta = lon2 - lon1;
    var y = Math.sin(lonDelta) * Math.cos(lat2);
    var x = Math.cos(lat1) * Math.sin(lat2) - Math.sin(lat1)
            * Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(lonDelta);
    var brng = Math.atan2(y, x);
    brng = brng * (180 / Math.PI);

    if (brng < 0) {
        brng += 360;
    }

    return brng;
    },

    destination : function(lat1, lon1, brng, dt, unit) {
    if (unit === undefined)
        unit = 'KM';
    var r = this.validateRadius(unit);
    lat1 *= Math.PI / 180;
    lon1 *= Math.PI / 180;
    var lat3 = Math.asin(Math.sin(lat1) * Math.cos(dt / r) + Math.cos(lat1)
            * Math.sin(dt / r) * Math.cos(brng * Math.PI / 180));
    var lon3 = lon1
            + Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng * Math.PI / 180) * Math.sin(dt / r)
                    * Math.cos(lat1), Math.cos(dt / r) - Math.sin(lat1)
                    * Math.sin(lat3));

    return {
        'LAT' : lat3 * 180 / Math.PI,
        'LON' : lon3 * 180 / Math.PI
    };
   }

 };

 angular.module('greatCircles', []).value('GreatCircle', GreatCircle)

   /*
    * window.onload = function(){ document.getElementById("dist").innerHTML 
    =
    * Math.round(( GreatCircle.distance(48.853139,2.368999, 48.826136, 
    2.321793) *
     * 10 ) // fake data. Shall be replaced with user location + restaurant 
     location
     * 10 ); }
     */
```

This is my server response when I am making call to - "http://localhost:3030/sez/api/user/ on browser"

```
  [
                            {
                                Name : '11111111111',
                                venueType : 'Electrician ',
                                subCuisine : 'Fan',
                                subsubCuisine : 'Greesing, Bnding',
                                address : 'abc',
                                city : 'test',
                                country : 'xxx',
                                countryCode : 'kk',
                                lat : 36.805273,
                                long : 73.355463,
                            },
                            {
                                Name : '222222222',
                                venueType : 'Electrician ',
                                subCuisine : 'Fan',
                                subsubCuisine : 'Greesing, Bnding',
                                address : 'hii',
                                city : 'xyz',
                                country : 'abc',
                                countryCode : 'oo',
                                lat : 85.320918,
                                long : 43.006271,
                            } ]
```

And this is the view -

```
  <div  ng-repeat="restaurant in restaurantList | orderBy: 'distance' | 
  limitTo:totalDisplayed" href="#">
        <article class="item_frame">
      <div class="marker_left_container">
        <span class="venu_type_text">{{restaurant.venueType}}</span>
        <span class="distance_from_user_rest"> distance: 
  {{distanceTo(restaurant)}}</span>
        <span class="distance_from_user_rest2">from current location</span>
      </div>
      <div class="restaurant_details_container">
        <h1 class="restaurant_name_inlist">{{restaurant.Name}}</h1>
        <span class="restaurant_detail_inlist2">{{restaurant.subCuisine}}  
   <br />

    {{restaurant.subsubCuisine}}</span>
        <span class="restaurant_address">{{restaurant.address}}, <br />
        </span>
        <span class="restaurant_address">{{restaurant.cp}}, 
   {{restaurant.city}}  <br />

        </span>
        <span class="restaurant_others">{{restaurant.phoneNumber}} <br />
        </span>
        <span class="restaurant_others">{{restaurant.website}}  <br />
        </span>
             </div>

      </article><!--main article frame 1 -->

    </div>
    <button class="button button-outline button-stable custom_button_lau" ng-click="loadMore()">Load more</button>
  </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this method to get data from server in your factory

```
    angular
        .module('wmapp.factory_restaurants', [ 'greatCircles' ])    
        .factory(
             'restaurantsFactory',
              function($http) {
                  return {
                     getRestaurants: function (url) {
                     return $http.get(url);
                   }
           };
        });
```

In controller file:

```
$scope.restaurantList = {};
restaurantsFactory.getRestaurants(url)
                .success(function (response) {
                    $scope.restaurantList = response;
                    console.log($scope.restaurantList);
                }, function (error) {
                    console.log("Error in getting data: " + error);
                });
```

Now In controller you can replace or perform any other calculation on received objects.

Comment: Can you please tell me if you are receiving any error in getting data (http response) or can send received response here

Comment: Error: [orderBy:notarray] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/orderBy/notarray?p0=%7B%22%24%24state%22%3A%7B%22status%22%3A-1%7D%7D
    at angular.min.js:6
    at angular.min.js:172
    at fn (eval at compile (angular.min.js:233), <anonymous>:4:256)
    at angular.min.js:128
    at m.$digest (angular.min.js:143)
    at m.$apply (angular.min.js:146)
    at l (angular.min.js:97)
    at J (angular.min.js:102)


Expected array but received: {"$$state":{"status":1,"value":{"data":

Comment: orderBy filter is not correct because it search 'distance' filed in restaurant object so try it by removing this filter and if you want distance filed then you take loop on restaurantList in controller and calculate distance and append it in restaurantList and then pass to UI

Comment: I updated my answer. Please check server data on console, it will definitely help you.

Comment: perfect, at least I can see some result now :) Thx - There are two issues on this
 #1 - distance shows "distance: NaN from current location"
#2 - In console, I can see this erroe one time "Error: orderBy:notarray Value is not array-like Expected array but received: {}" but after this, all fields are getting loaded

Comment: Because restaurantList does not have 'distance' object so you have to add this after receiving restaurantList from response.
{'distance': distanceTo(restaurantListObject)} concatenate it in every object of restaurantList.

Comment: Thx, actually from server I was returning "lon" instead of "long" - I just corrected in JS and every thing works perfectly (One minor issue I'm still looking #1- results are not accurate, the distance is not correct #2- after completing distance from one address to all stored address, still there is call going on to server.. continuesly without stop - looks like infinite loop)